# How to join two ARRAY<STRUCT> fields on a join key in Spark SQL 3.2

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

## Situation

I have a nested data structure featuring **multiple ARRAY<STRUCT> fields**. I'd like to flatten this data structure to end up with a flattened table in the end. The challenge is, that in those array fields there are structs that **share a reference key** that I need to keep together.

### Test data

#### Test data definition

```sql
%%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW school_class AS (
    SELECT
        'junior' AS student_age
        , array(
            named_struct('name', 'Andy',    'birthday', '2000-01-01')
          , named_struct('name', 'Beth',    'birthday', '2000-01-02')
          , named_struct('name', 'Charley', 'birthday', '2000-01-03')
          , named_struct('name', 'Doris',   'birthday', '2000-01-04')
        ) AS students
        , array(
            named_struct('subject', 'math', 'name', 'Andy',    'grade', 'A', 'favorite_number', 7 )
          , named_struct('subject', 'math', 'name', 'Charley', 'grade', 'C', 'favorite_number', 9)
          , named_struct('subject', 'math', 'name', 'Beth',    'grade', 'B', 'favorite_number', 42)
          
        ) AS students_math
        , array(
            named_struct('subject', 'chemistry', 'name', 'Beth',    'grade', 'B', 'favorite_element', 'Ti')
          , named_struct('subject', 'chemistry', 'name', 'Charley', 'grade', 'A', 'favorite_element', 'Kr')
          , named_struct('subject', 'chemistry', 'name', 'Doris',   'grade', 'A', 'favorite_element', 'Ne')
        ) AS students_chemistry
);
```

#### Schema of test data

```python
spark.read.table('school_class').printSchema()
root
 |-- student_age: string (nullable = false)
 |-- students: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- birthday: string (nullable = true)
 |-- students_math: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- subject: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- grade: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- favorite_number: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- students_chemistry: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- subject: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- grade: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- favorite_element: string (nullable = true)
```

## Desired result

I'd like to end up with a flat table as follows:

```
| student_age | name    | birthday   | grade_math | grade_chemistry |
| ----------- | ------- | ---------- | ---------- | --------------- |
| junior      | Andy    | 2000-01-01 | A          | null            |
| junior      | Beth    | 2000-01-02 | B          | B               |
| junior      | Charley | 2000-01-03 | C          | A               |
| junior      | Doris   | 2000-01-04 | null       | A               |
```

This can be achived using CTE/subqueries and explodes:

```sql
%%sql
WITH
  aux_students AS (
      SELECT 
        student_age
        , stud.name
        , stud.birthday
      FROM
        school_class
      LATERAL VIEW explode(students) exploded_students AS stud
  ),
  aux_students_m AS (
      SELECT 
        student_age
        , stud_m.name
        , stud_m.grade  AS grade_math
      FROM
        school_class
      LATERAL VIEW OUTER explode(students_math) exploded_students AS stud_m
  ),
  aux_students_ch AS (
      SELECT 
        student_age
        , stud_ch.name
        , stud_ch.grade AS grade_chemistry
      FROM
        school_class
      LATERAL VIEW OUTER explode(students_chemistry) exploded_students AS stud_ch
  )
SELECT aux_students.*, aux_students_m.grade_math, aux_students_ch.grade_chemistry  FROM aux_students
LEFT JOIN aux_students_m ON (aux_students.student_age = aux_students_m.student_age AND aux_students.name = aux_students_m.name)
LEFT JOIN aux_students_ch ON (aux_students.student_age = aux_students_ch.student_age AND aux_students.name = aux_students_ch.name);
```

## Is there a better way?

I am looking for a more elegant way, since my current solution will not scale properly if the original data structure would contain thousands of rows. I think in that case, the join would consider more rows than it actually need to since the views contain all rows for all "student_age".

I stumbled across the [**arrays_zip**](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/arrays_zip.html) function. This is nearly what I want to do: it joins two or more ARRAY<STRUCT>. However, It does the join **not considering a join criterion** (ON-clause in SQL) but only on the **position of the array elements**:

```sql
%%sql
SELECT
  student_age
  , s.students.name
  , s.students.birthday
  , s.students_math.grade AS grade_math
  , s.students_chemistry.grade AS grade_chemistry
FROM
  school_class
LATERAL VIEW explode(arrays_zip(students, students_math, students_chemistry)) expl AS s
;
```

The **result is wrong** , since not all elements are present in all arrays and the elements are not sorted on the join key ("name") Result:

```
| student_age | name    | birthday   | grade_math | grade_chemistry |
| ----------- | ------- | ---------- | ---------- | --------------- |
| junior      | Andy    | 2000-01-01 | A        | B             |
| junior      | Beth    | 2000-01-02 | C        | A             |
| junior      | Charley | 2000-01-03 | B        | A               |
| junior      | Doris   | 2000-01-04 | null       | null          |
```

### Questions

1. Is there some similar functionality to arrays_zip that let me specify the **join-condition**?
2. Is there some some workaround by **making sure that all elements are present** in the arrays (e.g. create dummy null values) and **sort the arrays** before applying *arrays_zip*?
3. Is there a completely different approach for solving my problem?